# How to convert .dmg to Directory-folder

Tags: macos, disk-utility, dmg

I just Create one Directory to .dmg file using Disk Utility. Can anyone Please Tel me how to convert .dmg file in to older Directory-folder.

Answer (score 5):

Mount it, and then copy?

Why won't that work?

Comment: Because you might lose icon positions, ownership information, access rights, asf.

Answer (score 2):

Mounting it first is definitely what Apple intended with the format, but I recently found a sketchy (via CNET) version of a package and was curious how it differed from the official version. I didn't trust OS X to mount it without potentially auto-running any malware it might have, so I just wanted a clean filesystem extract.

Turns out, (p)7-zip can do it! Supposing your disk image is named `sketchy.dmg`:

```
brew install p7zip
7z x sketchy.dmg
```

Which will extract everything in the image into the current directory, not necessarily into a new subdirectory like double-clicking `.zip` files in Finder does.